# Sweet, black, and many

Tags: riddle

I start green, hard and raw,
Then red, but still inedible,
Finally black with beads dark as ebony,
I come by the many with my brothers,
Sweet, fresh and good to eat.

What am I?

Comment: One thing you might want to do is wait 12-24 hours to accept the answer, so you can get more views (and votes!) :)

Comment: Ok I think I will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are they:

> blackberries?

Because:

> they start green, then turn red, then you can eat them when they turn black, and there are a lot of them

Comment: ahhhh I sniped you by just a couple minutes +1 :D

Comment: Awww, so close!

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Blackberry

I start green, hard and raw,

> Firs they are green.

Then red, but still inedible,

> Then they turn a reddish color.

Finally black with beads dark as ebony,

> *Black* berries.

I come by the many with my brothers,

> Berries and other fruits.

Sweet, fresh and good to eat.

> Fruit is healthy.

Comment: Wow everyone is so good at this well done!